# How do i make my picture relocate it self on the screen with a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, user-interface

Im learning Xcode and i was wondering how to make a button refresh part of my code or something. Im placing a picture in a random location on my screen but i want to be able to press the button to relocate it to another random location, any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. This is my code. ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
int xValue = arc4random() % 320;
int yValue = arc4random() % 480;


UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, 70, 30)];
NSString *imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clubs-2-150" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilepath];
[imgView setImage:img];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];


[super viewDidLoad];   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code stands right now it is not possible Variables have a scope, that means, they only exists within certain functions or classes. You variable `imgView` only exists on `viewDidLoad`. For you to be able to access it somewhere else you need to declare it as an instance variable.

on your .h file to this:

```
@interface yourClassName : UIViewController {
   UIImage *imageIWantToChange;
}
```

This will let you access imageIWantToChange in all of your yourClassName functions.

Now, on your .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];   

   int xValue = arc4random() % 320;
   int yValue = arc4random() % 480;

   //Notice that we do not have UIImage before imageIWantToChange
   imageIWantToChange = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, 70, 30)];
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clubs-2-150.jpg"];
   [imageIWantToChange setImage:img];
   [self.view addSubview:imgView];

}
```

Then in your IBAction or button selector:

```
-(IBAction) buttonWasPressed:(id) sender {
   CGRect frame = imageIWantToChange.frame;

   frame.origin.x = arc4random() % 320;
   frame.origin.y = arc4random() % 480;

   imageIWantToChange.frame = frame;
}
```